# Android development java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, boot

I am currently developing part of my app to launch when the device boots up. I am doing this for a good reason, to run a background process that detects movement, i am not trying to spam the user or show them an interface when they turn the device on.
The problem I am facing is an error that looks like this, I have not idea what it is:

```
12-22 17:00:53.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1629): Process: com.dd.splash, PID: 1629
12-22 17:00:53.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1629): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.dd.splash.MyActivity: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.dd.splash.MyActivity cannot be cast to android.content.BroadcastReceiver
12-22 17:00:53.399: E/AndroidRuntime(1629): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.dd.splash.MyActivity cannot be cast to android.content.BroadcastReceiver
```

Here are the faulty code snippets

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<receiver 
        android:enabled="true" 
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

MyActivity.java

```
public class MyActivity {
//The code that I want in the process will go here soon!
}
```

So, I install my app, reboot my device, and get an error saying that my app has stopped unexpectedly. I look in the running processes, and the app does not appear there, nor in cached processes. What is the problem? It looks like the error is saying that the two files can't communicate. I think im making a dumb mistake, if somebody could please point it out.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you everything:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: **com.dd.splash.MyActivity cannot be cast to android.content.BroadcastReceiver**

As you have shown, your code for MyActivity is:

```
public class MyActivity {

}
```

So asumming you want it to be a receiver, you need to extend BroadcastReceiver, and override its' onReceive() method, like so:

```
public class MyActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //code to run when receiver fires    
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks a bit better but im getting these errors: `Multiple markers at this line
 - BroadcastReceiver cannot be resolved to a type
 - The type MyActivity must implement the inherited abstract method 
  BroadcastReceiver.onReceive(Context, Intent)`

Comment: Again, the error tells you what you need to do: override onReceive()  in your MyActivity, as shown in my answer :)

Comment: Ohh wait i got it! I need the correct `import` lines! Thanks for your help! But one more quick thing, my app doesn't show up under running processes on my nexus, any ideas? Maybe that's because its not actually doing anything yet?

Comment: Or do i have to include `Intent i = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);  
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i); ` somewhere?

Comment: Oh found the error `Unable to start receiver com.dd.splash.MyActivity: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.dd.splash/com.dd.splash.MyActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?` So i have to declare the activity in android manifest.xml... how do i do that?